# php openssl encrypt data with aes256 and use a sha256 hashed pass help!

Tags: php, openssl

openssl only accepting half of a sha256 hashed password
`$encryptedkey = openssl_encrypt ($data, 'AES256', "$sha256", $raw_output = false);`

hash looks like this:a0461cea77b9942addee32b2265b32ebcf150426e2490810938ab47206fd320b

its only accepting 32 characters of it:a0461cea77b9942addee32b2265b32eb
how can i fix this? thank you! 

edit: example: when decrypting the data if the hash does not mach after 32 character it will still decrypt it even if its wrong 
a0461cea77b9942addee32b2265b32ebcf150426e2490810938ab47206fd320b
a0461cea77b9942addee32b2265b32ebcf150426e24808019485b43406df3a9b
both will work when they shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you should pass the raw data, not an hexadecimal representation of it. I say this because 32*8=256, hence by reading 32 characters, the function is actually reading 256 bits.

Try passing `pack("H*", $sha256)` instead of `$sha256`.

Comment: Is that a secure what of converting it?<br>
this is what it did to the hash: "‚•É+3�6B™Ó¤R- Kai%¡þÊnª

Comment: @user Sure, that's just the raw representation. You can see that e.g. `pack("H*", hash("sha256", "mydata")) == hash("sha256", "mydata", true)`.

Comment: Ok i think i get it
$hash3 = hash('SHA256',$data2);
$hash4 = pack("H*", $hash3);

$hash5 = bin2hex($hash4);

echo $hash5 -- the same
echo $hash3 -- the same
echo $hash4 -- "‚•É+3�6B™Ó¤R- Kai%¡þÊnª